# External files not loading into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem loading external files into my index.html. My stylesheet as well as my JS files do not show up at all (Error 404 - Not Found). My directory structure is as follows.

[image: File Structure]

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Orders and Customers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./../app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./../app/controllers/customer/CustomerController.js"></script>
    <script src="./../app/controllers/order/OrderController.js"></script>
    <script src="./../app/services/customer/CustomerService.js"></script>
    <script src="./../app/services/order/OrderService.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what Chrome shows:

[image]

My server.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('./server/config/mongoose.js');
require('./server/config/routes.js')(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views')));

app.listen(8000, function() {
console.log('Listening on Port 8000');
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using `../assets/css/stylesheet.css` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

in server.js

```
var router = express.Router();
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../app")));
```

in index.html

```
<script src="/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/controllers/customer/CustomerController.js"></script>
<script src="/controllers/order/OrderController.js"></script>
<script src="/services/customer/CustomerService.js"></script>
<script src="/services/order/OrderService.js"></script>
```

`Router` is middle-ware for capture `*` path.
For example, `/service/*` matches all requests under service path.
so I changed your code as to handle all resources under "/app" folder. (eg: `/app/app.js`, etc)

`path.resolve` changes path from relative to absolute.
it means that you can add another current working directory.
`path.resolve(__dirname, "../app")` add `"/app"` from current working directory (`views`). it parsed from `"views/../app"` to `"/app"`

---

(Reference) [Path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to)

Comment: Omg you're a life saver. So what I did was a little different. I'm pretty new to the MEAN stack (and programming in general) and it seems that I don't fully understand what express.static does. Instead of using express.Router(), I actually just created another static path that pointed towards my 'app' folder and used the source paths that you listed in my HTML and low and behold, everything is working great. I will definitely look into path.resolve as I think that is something that would have also been an excellent solution. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: 1 more question if you don't mind. Are angular components (i.e controllers, services, partial views, etc) considered to be static content? I was under the impression that they were dynamic.

Comment: `express.static` does not means **"It handles static contents"**. It gives a way for server to react request. so it can handle `/app.js` path. Tim's dynamic functionality fired not http request but under javascript engine.

Answer (score 0):

The relative paths

```
<script src="./../app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

etc, are pointing to the wrong directory.

Use the Network tab in your browser developer tools, to check what exact requests are going out.

If the whole app directory is public (Which, in my opinion, should not be the case), "./../" will refer to the **views** directory.
Single . refers to the current directory, which in this case is, the one containing your index.html. Double .. refers to the directory above it, which here is **views**.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The directory looks a bit weird but the index.html is actually in the views folder so wouldn't "./" refer to the views folder and './../' refer to the root directory?

EDIT: Uploaded a picture of the Network tab.

Comment: Your root directory is not public. The files in it are not statically hosted, and they shouldn't be. Your public directory seems to be the views directory. So try moving all your static content (jss, css, images, etc) under the views directory and reference it relative to views directory.

So, if you have app.js in views/js/app.js, in your html, refer it to as `<script src="/js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: Hey Hammad, thanks for the reply again. I brought in one of the controllers and its associated factory into a folder called 'js' that is in the same path as index.html. Unfortunately, this did not remedy the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
<script src="./../app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Try using the full path:

```
<script src="/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/app/controllers/order/OrderController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but the errors are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

and just use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SeongHyeon, I was able to figure out the solution to my problem. I really appreciate your guys' help. I'd like to elaborate more on this just for my own reference.

When declaring your static path in express, you don't need to reference anything relative to the file that you're trying to import from. Instead, you simply reference the file from the static path that you've declared.